# The name of the picture

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

Yesterday, I dabbled in a bit of computer art:

[image]

While @AxiomaticSystem was quick to find out the [secret procedure](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/111532/73836) I used to create it they left one mystery intact:

What is the name of the picture?

Hint:

> As word plays go this is more of an allusion than a genuine pun.

Cryptic hint:

> Not a wooden thynge (nor thijng) that helps you getting over a fence.

**UPDATE 2022/08**

Big fat hint:

> [What may this stijl icon be called?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_and_Blue_Chair#/media/File:Gerrit_thomas_rietveld,_red-blue_chair,_1946-56_ca.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

"Can you either reproduce it or describe the algorithm I used?"

It may be hard to reproduce due to the:

> irreptile dysfunction?

Comment: This is a clever pun---and as such, sadly, kind of ruled out in the hint. I had something more pedestrian  and obvious (and cleaner ;-) ) in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the [naming from Florian F's deleted answer](https://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution/ammann-chair/) and the [Big Fat Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_and_Blue_Chair), is the answer

> Red and Blue Ammann Chair

Comment: "Ammann" is a bit too specific for it to be an allusion. And it is not a single one ;-)))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you named it "LL Cool J" because of the L's and J's, and maybe cool describes the blue? Or maybe even a variant name like "Red L Cool J?"

Comment: I'm not sure you're taking this seriously ;-P

Comment: You said [allusion](https://www.ereadingworksheets.com/figurative-language/poetic-devices/allusion-examples/)- You got allusion!  :)